# Node Express Mongodb connection syntax and error handling

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I was having an issue in my app that was simply from an oversight on the database name that I provided to my mongodb connection.  While looking around I ran across the examples here:

```
https://wesleytsai.io/2015/08/02/mongodb-connection-pooling-in-nodejs/
```

So my question is why don't I get any kind of error thrown if I am providing a database that does not exist to the mongodb connection?  I just need help interpreting/understanding the syntax below.  On this line:

```
MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, function(err, database) { 
    if( err ) throw err;
.
.
.
```

shouldn't an error be thrown since mongo can't connect if the database doesn't exist?

What I'm trying to do is setup some kind of error handling that can flag the fact the the database doesn't exist and likewise with the collection if that too does not exist ('expenses' should be 'test').

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var mongoUrl = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/expenses';
var db;

exports.connect = function(callback) {
  MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, function(err, database) {
    if( err ) throw err;
    db = database;
    callback();
  })
}
```

Comment: if you started your mongod within the system its fine. And if you are connecting via mlab then you need to provide a link. Are you doing any of these?

Answer (score 0):

In mongodb, if you are connected to the datbase and then you provide a schema to a collection that you defined, then irrespective of the fact that whether that collection is there or not, mongodb creates a collection for you.

For example if you have the following code,

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', schema);
```

a collection named users is created in the database. So even if you dont have a collection, mongodb will create one for you.

If you want to check whether a database exists then follow like below:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
    , Admin = mongoose.mongo.Admin;

/// create a connection to ypur database
var connection = mongoose.createConnection(
    'mongodb://user:password@localhost:port/your_database');
connection.on('open', function() {
    // connection successful
    new Admin(connection.db).listDatabases(function(err, result) {
        console.log('listDatabases successful');
        // the database lists are stored in result.databases
        var allDatabases = result.databases; 
        // allDatabases contains the record of all the databases
        // crosscheck this list with the database you want 
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that mongodb functions that way in the shell.    However, my question is how to flag the fact that the database that I'm trying to connect to does not exist.  In my case, this was in the context of a restful api.  I was simply not getting any data and no errors at all anywhere.  I just want to find a way to handle this so in the future I can know that the database is not being connected to.

Comment: the edited content above will gives you a result that contains all the lists of databases in that connection. Cross check with the one you want, so that you can avoid future problems.